# Convert text in MorseCode using Java Hash map

Tags: java

I have to develop a method that take as parameter a String and transform it into Morse code i decide to use `HashMap` but I don't know how to get specific value for letter (I set letters as key).

```
package com.company;

import java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException;
import java.util.*;

public class MorseCode {


public void transformInMorseCode(String prop) {
    HashMap<String, String> morseMap = new HashMap<>();
    morseMap.put("A", ".-");
    morseMap.put("B", "-...");
    morseMap.put("C", "-.-.");
    morseMap.put("D", "-..");
    morseMap.put("E", ".");
    morseMap.put("F", "..-.");
    morseMap.put("G", "--.");
    morseMap.put("H", "....");
    morseMap.put("I", "..");
    morseMap.put("J", ".---");
    morseMap.put("K", "-.-");
    morseMap.put("L", ".-..");
    morseMap.put("M", "--");
    morseMap.put("N", "-.");
    morseMap.put("O", "---");
    morseMap.put("P", ".--.");
    morseMap.put("Q", "--.-");
    morseMap.put("R", ".-.");
    morseMap.put("S", "...");
    morseMap.put("T", "-");
    morseMap.put("U", "..-");
    morseMap.put("V", "...-");
    morseMap.put("W", ".--");
    morseMap.put("X", "-..-");
    morseMap.put("Y", "-.--");
    morseMap.put("Z", "--..");
    morseMap.put("1", ".----");
    morseMap.put("2", "..---");
    morseMap.put("3", "...--");
    morseMap.put("4", "....-");
    morseMap.put("5", ".....");
    morseMap.put("6", "-....");
    morseMap.put("7", "--...");
    morseMap.put("8", "---..");
    morseMap.put("9", "----.");
    morseMap.put("0", "-----");


    String[] propFinala = prop.split(" ");


    for (String s : propFinala) {

        if (s.equals(morseMap.keySet())) {

        }
    }


}


}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will helps you:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : prop.toCharArray())
    if (morseMap.containsKey(("" + c).toUpperCase()))
        result.append(morseMap.get(("" + c).toUpperCase()));
```

Also you should add space() which equals to `/` to morse code map:

```
morseMap.put(" ", "/");
```

Comment: I try but it show nothing, When i add System.out.println(result);

Comment: @MisaD. what is your input?

Comment: I imput word MAMA

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the characters and get the uppercase variant with the `toUpperCase()`. With this as key you can get the map value by using the `map[key]` method. See the code below

```
for (String s : propFinala) {
    String code = morseMap[s.toUpperCase()]
    //Do what you awant with your `code` variable below
}
```